# Inject Omnifaces PushContext in a bean managed by Spring

Tags: spring, jsf-2.2, omnifaces

I have an JSF app running on WildFly 10 and Primefaces 6.2 and Omnifaces 2.6.2.

My Beans are managed by Spring like this:

```
@Controller
@Scope("session")
public class CompanySelectionController implements Serializable {
```

I'm trying to implement Omnifaces WebSockets
However when I try to inject PushContext like below:

```
@Inject @Push
private PushContext someChannel;
```

it says "No qualifying bean of type [org.omnifaces.cdi.PushContext]"

What should I do in this case?

Comment: Make the Spring bean into a did one?

Comment: Sorry, into what?

Comment: Hahaha sorry, bad auto-correction. A CDI bean (not 'did')

Comment: Oh xD I see, however if I do that I won't be able to inject my spring services. I wonder if I'm able to teach Spring how to produce this dependency so it could inject it ...

Comment: I don't do Spring, but theoretically you basically need to manually re-register all CDI-managed beans as Spring-managed beans in some Spring-specific XML configuration file. Not sure though if the whole `@Push` would then work as designed.